# Unable to add Trend Line in Tableau even though both axes are numeric

Tags: tableau-api

As shown in the screenshot: both axes are numeric. So why can not the trend line be calculated?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with this set up is that the values on the x-axis are discrete values rather than a measure.
Tableau treats every number as a separate category rather than a point on an axis. 
If you click on that field and chose "Convert to measure", you should get an actual scatterplot and you should then be able to add a reference line for each axis.

Comment: I will try this out. If it were in fact the correct answer then ***big -1*** to Tableau for their poor error message.